# How to get exchange rates for testnets?

Tags: testnets, exchanges, kovan

I would like to see what a PETH on Kovan is worth in DAI. How can you look for exchange rates on testnets?

Comment: Note that the testnets could theoretically disappear at any time (and have done in the past).

Answer (score 1):

There are no exchange rates for test networks as none of the assets are worth anything. They are all valued at zero.

You can get free Ethers from a testnew faucet and use those to exchange to any other tokens. The exchange rate may be basically anything - it makes no difference whether you pay 1 Ether or 1 wei to get your tokens as you can always get more free Ethers. And probably there are free token faucets as well, at least for some tokens.